# How to filter related objects in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Could anyone help me with this here.
I have a user table like this in mysql database:

```
MariaDB [tiro]> SELECT * FROM user_tb;
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | dias       | maria     |
|  2 | paulo      | heleno    |
|  3 | silas      | raimundo  |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

And this one for questions:
**NOTE:** It has a foreign key to user_tb.

```
MariaDB [tiro]> SELECT * FROM question_tb;
+----+-------------------------+-------------+
| id | question                | asked_by_id |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+
|  1 | whats up                |           1 |
|  2 | who is out there        |           1 |
|  3 | where do we party today |           3 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+
```

And the other for answers:
**NOTE:** It has foreign key to user_tb and question_tb.

```
MariaDB [tiro]> SELECT * FROM answer_tb;
+----+---------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
| id | answer                          | question_id | answered_by_id |
+----+---------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
|  2 | the man in control of you house |           2 |              1 |
|  3 | nothing at all                  |           1 |              1 |
|  4 | lets party at my house guys     |           3 |              1 |
|  5 | casino is the best place        |           3 |              2 |
|  6 | its your enemy                  |           2 |              2 |
|  7 | we are fuck this world          |           1 |              3 |
+----+---------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
```

The tables have all data that i need to filter. Here i want to filter all questions that the user with id 1 have a answer but exclude all answers answered by other users to that question.

User id 1 has a answer at question id 2 and also the user id 2  too. How could i get question id 2 with only answer of user 1 leaving out user 2. is it possible? My brain is locked here, Please help.

Comment: Can you add the expected results?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM answer_tb WHERE question_id = 2 AND answered_by_id = 1` maybe? Or is that too simple? Seems too simple to be causing such trouble. If you want the question text too, do an inner join to the question table using the question_id

Comment: user "dias maria" have a answer in question 1,2,3. And user "paulo heleno" have answer too at question 2 but , when i get it for "dias maria",i want to eXclude paulo heleno's answer inside the queryset.

Comment: and does my suggested query achieve that? It will select only rows which were answered by id 1, which is dias maria. So automatically, every other user is excluded. Did you understand what I wrote? Did you try it? Do you know what a WHERE clause is in SQL?

Comment: wow,it does the magic... thankks AD

Comment: I added the answer below - please mark as "accepted". And it's not magic, it's quite simple SQL :-)

Comment: So what is a workaround if i need all questions that "dias maria" has answers but eXclude others user answers in all those returned questions

Comment: So what is a workaround if i need all questions that "dias maria" has answers but eXclude others user answers in all those returned questions

Comment: If you want all the answers (not just question 2) then simply remove the part of the WHERE clause which restricts the question ID to question 2. I worry that you do not actually understand anything at all about the code? This is _really_ simple SQL. Take a tutorial if you cannot understand a WHERE clause. But even then, I would that thought that "question_id = 2" was pretty self-explanatory, no?

Comment: Also please remember to mark the answer as "accepted", if it helped you. Click the tick mark next to the question so that it turns green.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have correctly understood your intentions, but if I have, I believe that the answer is as simple as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM question_tb
JOIN answer_tb ON answer_tb.question_id = question_tb.id
WHERE answered_by_id = 1; <- replace this with your desired ID
```

This query just retrieves all existing question-answer pairs and filters out all pairs consisting of an answer from someone else than from the specified user.

Example output:

```
+----------------+-------------------------+-------------++--------------+---------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
| question_tb.id | question                | asked_by_id || answer_tb.id | answer                          | question_id | answered_by_id |
+----------------+-------------------------+-------------++--------------+---------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
|              1 | whats up                |           1 ||            3 | nothing at all                  |           1 |              1 |
|              2 | who is out there        |           1 ||            2 | the man in control of you house |           2 |              1 |
|              3 | where do we party today |           3 ||            4 | lets party at my house guys     |           3 |              1 |
+----------------+-------------------------+-------------++--------------+---------------------------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Cheer Jira, your answer is 100% what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, you want to get the answer to question 2, but only the answer given by user "dias maria", whose user ID is 1.

A couple of simple "WHERE" clauses can achieve that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM answer_tb 
WHERE question_id = 2 AND answered_by_id = 1
```

If you wish to output extra details such as the question text and the user's name, you can join to those tables too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM answer_tb 
INNER JOIN user_tb ON user_tb.id = answer_tb.answered_by_id
INNER JOIN question_tb ON question_tb.id = answer_tb.question_id
WHERE answer_tb.question_id = 2 AND answer_tb.answered_by_id = 1
```

This is quite basic SQL so I suggest you do a little more study if this is giving you a headache.